# Prove that $y^3=x^2+2^{16}3^9$ has no integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Prove that $y^3=x^2+2^{16}3^9$ has no integer solutions.

Let $k=2^83^4,$ then $y^3=x^2+3k^2=(x+\sqrt{-3}k)(x-\sqrt{-3}k),$ but that's going to be complex.

I wonder is there a better way to solve this problem?

Edit: Sorry, this statement is **NOT** true, since $1728^3=62208^2+2^{16}3^9.$
I saw this problem from a website, but that OP gave me a false statement..

Comment: Do you mean $3^{4.5}$?

Comment: @nbubis $3k^2=3\cdot2^{16}3^8=2^{16}3^9$

Comment: Do you mean you want to avoid the use of extensions of number-fields?

Comment: @Hecke Don't you want to solve it by ANT ?

Comment: @awllower No, I just think it will be complex because we need to consider the GCD of $x$ and $k$.

Comment: @what'sup Sorry, but what's ANT?

Comment: An observation (whether it be interesting or not). Let $p$ be any odd prime factor of $y$. Then $x^2 = -2^{16} 3^9 (\mathrm{mod} \ p)$, whence the Legendre symbol $(-2^{16} 3^9|p)=1$ that is $(-1|p)(3|p)=1$, which implies $p=1 (\mathrm{mod} \ 12)$ or $p=-5 (\mathrm{mod} \ 12)$. Checking squares $(\mathrm{mod} \ 12)$ it is easy to see that only $p=1(\mathrm{mod} \ 12)$ is possible. However, I am not sure where this leads.

Comment: sorry ANT = algebraic number theory

Comment: @what'sup Not avoid, it's better if you can give a complete proof.

Comment: sorry my answer was very wrong i'll try again 

thanks @awllower

Comment: or i'll just sleep :-)

Comment: @what'sup NP! I think your answer is still quite a potential one. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let us first observe that, for $p=2$ or $3$, if $p\mid x$, then $p\mid y$, so $p^2\mid x$, hence $p^2\mid y,$ and $p^3\mid x.$
Therefore there are six cases, respectively given by the equations $y^3=x^2+k,$ with $k=2^{k_1}3^{k_2},$ where $k_1\in\{16,10,4\}, k_2\in\{9,3\}.$ In each of these, $x$ is relatively prime to both $2$ and $3$.
Now let $k'_1=k_1/2, k'_2=(k_2-1)/2$ and write $y^3=(x-k'\sqrt{-3})(x+ik'\sqrt{-3}),$ where $k'=2^{k'_1}3^{k'_2}.$
Now, by means of [Minkowski bound](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/classgpex.pdf), or of any other standard calculations, we know that the class-number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$ is $1$. Thus, by our assumptions, we know that there are $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$ such that, setting $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}, \beta=a+b\alpha, \gamma=c+d\alpha,$ we have that $y=\beta\gamma, x-k'\sqrt{-3}=\epsilon\beta^3, x+k'\sqrt{-3}=\epsilon'\gamma^3,$ where $\epsilon,\epsilon'$ are units.
Now the unit group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$ is a cyclic group of order $6$ generated by $\alpha.$ So all units are powers of $\alpha$; say $\epsilon=\alpha^m$.
Expanding out the equations, we find that $-k'=\pm\begin{cases}3ab(a+b)/2\\(a^3-b^3+3a^2b)/2\\(a^3-b^3-3ab^2)/2\end{cases}.$
Hence our problem now is to examine closely these $18$ cases.
Indeed this is messy and is incomplete as it stands now.
Maybe this is not what OP wants? If so, I shall delete it then. And thanks for the attention.